# Replace individual list elements in Haskell?

Tags: list, haskell, state

I have a list of elements and I wish to update them:

from this: `["Off","Off","Off","Off"]`

to this:  `["Off","Off","On","Off"]`

As I am somewhat new to Haskell, I have been using `(x:xs)!!y` to extract and update individual components using the function:

```
replace y z [] = []
replace y z (x:xs)
  | x==y           = z:replace y z xs
  | otherwise      = x:replace y z xs
```

and then entering the following in ghci: `(replace "Off" "On" ["Off",'Off","Off","Off"]) !! 2`

I get the following: `"On"`

I seem to be able to extract and convert elements of a list but I can't seem to get a list up with the single element converted.

Any help regarding this matter would be appreciated.

Comment: This is the reason i gave up on Haskell...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do.  If you only need to generate ["Off","Off","On","Off"]  you can do it explicitly.  Generally speaking, one should avoid modifying state in haskell.

Perhaps what you want is a function to "modify" (generate a new element with a different value) the nth element of a list?  Don gives a very general approach to this kind of problem.
You can also use explicit recursion:

```
 replaceNth :: Int -> a -> [a] -> [a]
 replaceNth _ _ [] = []
 replaceNth n newVal (x:xs)
   | n == 0 = newVal:xs
   | otherwise = x:replaceNth (n-1) newVal xs
```

Haskell provides excellent features for list manipulation.  If you dont know them already `filter`, `map`, and `foldr`/`foldl` are all worth looking at, as are list comprehensions.

Comment: Consider the more general `modifyNth :: Int -> (a -> a) -> [a] -> [a]`, which takes a function to modify the element, instead of a hard-coded new value. This function can now be implemented as `replaceNth n newVal = modifyNth n (const newVal)`

Comment: This is why Haskell is not used. It's really a joke to do all these just to modify one element

Answer (score 65):

Typically, you modify elements of a list by splitting the list, replacing an element, and joining it back together.

To split a list at an index, we have:

```
 splitAt :: Int -> [a] -> ([a], [a])
```

which you can use to break up a list, like so:

```
 > splitAt 2 ["Off","Off","Off","Off"] 
 (["Off","Off"],["Off","Off"])
```

now you just need to pop the head element of the `snd` component of the list. This is easily done with *pattern matching*:

```
 > let (x,_:ys) = splitAt 2 ["Off","Off","Off","Off"]
 > x
 ["Off","Off"]
 > ys
 ["Off"]
```

you can now join the list back together, with an "On":

```
 > x ++ "On" : ys
 ["Off","Off","On","Off"]
```

I'll leave it to you to put those pieces together into a single function.

---

As a style note, I'd suggest using a new custom data type, instead of `String` for your toggles:

```
 data Toggle = On | Off deriving Show
```

Comment: This won't work for replacing the last element of a list

Answer (score 42):

### Changing the nth element

A common operation in many languages is to assign to an indexed position in an array.  In python you might:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> a[3] = 9
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 9, 5]
```

The
[lens](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens) package gives this functionality with the `(.~)` operator.  Though unlike in python the original list is not mutated, rather a new list is returned.

```
> let a = [1,2,3,4,5]
> a & element 3 .~ 9
[1,2,3,9,5]
> a
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

`element 3 .~ 9` is just a function and the `(&)` operator, part of the
[lens](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens) package, is just reverse function application.  Here it is with more common function application.

```
> (element 3 .~ 9) [1,2,3,4,5]
[1,2,3,9,5]
```

Assignment again works perfectly fine with arbitrary nesting of `Traversable`s.

```
> [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]] & element 0 . element 1 .~ 9
[[1,9,3],[4,5,6]]
```

or

```
> set (element 3) 9 [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

Or if you want to effect multiple elements you can use:

```
> over (elements (>3)) (const 99) [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
> [1,2,3,4,99,99,99]
```

### Working with types other than lists

This is not just limited to lists however, it will work with any datatype that is an instance of the [Traversable](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.1.2/docs/Control-Lens-Traversal.html#t:Traversable) typeclass.

Take for example the same technique works on [trees](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.5.1/docs/Data-Tree.html) form the standard
[containers](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers) package.

```
 > import Data.Tree
 > :{
 let
  tree = Node 1 [
       Node 2 [Node 4[], Node 5 []]
     , Node 3 [Node 6 [], Node 7 []]
     ]
 :}
> putStrLn . drawTree . fmap show $ tree
1
|
+- 2
|  |
|  +- 4
|  |
|  `- 5
|
`- 3
   |
   +- 6
   |
   `- 7
> putStrLn . drawTree . fmap show $ tree & element 1 .~ 99
1
|
+- 99
|  |
|  +- 4
|  |
|  `- 5
|
`- 3
   |
   +- 6
   |
   `- 7
> putStrLn . drawTree . fmap show $ tree & element 3 .~ 99
1
|
+- 2
|  |
|  +- 4
|  |
|  `- 99
|
`- 3
   |
   +- 6
   |
   `- 7
> putStrLn . drawTree . fmap show $ over (elements (>3)) (const 99) tree
1
|
+- 2
|  |
|  +- 4
|  |
|  `- 5
|
`- 99
   |
   +- 99
   |
   `- 99
```

Answer (score 11):

Here is a one liner that works perfectly

```
replace pos newVal list = take pos list ++ newVal : drop (pos+1) list
```

I doesn't seem efficient to do this kind of things in haskell.

Comment: `++` has poor performance whenever its second argument is long. That's the reason for `ShowS`; a recursive approach would probably perform better.

Answer (score 6):

Here's some code that I've been using:

```
-- | Replaces an element in a list with a new element, if that element exists.
safeReplaceElement
  -- | The list
  :: [a]
  -- | Index of the element to replace.
  -> Int
  -- | The new element.
  -> a
  -- | The updated list.
  -> [a]
safeReplaceElement xs i x =
  if i >= 0 && i < length xs
    then replaceElement xs i x
    else xs


-- | Replaces an element in a list with a new element.
replaceElement
  -- | The list
  :: [a]
  -- | Index of the element to replace.
  -> Int
  -- | The new element.
  -> a
  -- | The updated list.
  -> [a]
replaceElement xs i x = fore ++ (x : aft)
  where fore = take i xs
        aft = drop (i+1) xs
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually, for many cases (not always) where you'd use a List, a Data.Vector is a better choice.

It comes with an update function, see [Hackage](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.11.0.0/docs/Data-Vector-Generic.html#g:15), that does exactly what you need.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should consider using a data structure other than List.  For example, if you just want to have a state of four on/off switches then:

```
data State = St { sw1, sw2, sw3, sw4 :: Bool }
```

For a dynamic number of switches then consider a mapping from `switch name` to `Bool`.

Comment: For a dynamic number of switches I would suggest a `Vector`, or possibly an `IntMap`.

Comment: @John Right, depending on your exact needs the mapping could be a Map, IntMap, or HashMap (or even something else).  Why would you suggest a Vector though?  If it's static for each run, sure, but if the number of switches actually needs to grow or shrink that's something Vector can't do well.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is more elegant way of replacing an individual element:

```
setelt:: Int -> [a] -> a -> [a]

setelt i list newValue = 
  let (ys,zs) = splitAt i-1 list in  ys ++ newValue ++ tail zs
```

There is input error handling. 
So if index *i* is out of boundaries haskell will show wrong output. (Note: in Haskell indexing starts from 1 onwards)

Hugs would behave as follows:

```
Main> setelt 1 [1,2,3] 9
[9,2,3]
Main> setelt 3 [1,2,3] 9
[1,2,9]
Main> setelt 0 [1,2,3] 9
[9,2,3]
Main> setelt 4 [1,2,3] 9
[1,2,3,9]
Program error: pattern match failure: tail []
```

Error handling at your service:

```
setelt i y newValue = 
    if and [i>0, i<= length y]
    then let (ys,zs) = splitAt (i-1) y in  ys ++ [newValue] ++ tail zs
    else y
```

if index you give is wrong it returns original list.

Answer (score 0):

This answer arrives quite late, but I thought I'd share what I think is an **efficient** way of replacing the `nth` element in a list in Haskell. I'm new to Haskell and thought I'd pitch in.

The `set` function *sets* the nth element in a list to a given value:

```
set' :: Int -> Int -> a -> [a] -> [a]
set' _ _ _ [] = []
set' ind curr new arr@(x:xs)
    | curr > ind = arr
    | ind == curr = new:(set' ind (curr+1) new xs)
    | otherwise = x:(set' ind (curr+1) new xs)

set :: Int -> a -> [a] -> [a]
set ind new arr = (set' ind 0 new arr)
```

As `set` traverses a list, it breaks the list apart and if the current index is the given `n` it combines the previous element with the given new value, otherwise, it combines the previous element with the old value in the list for that index.