# Update 'x'th element of list - Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, element, variable-assignment

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Replace individual list elements in Haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5852722/replace-individual-list-elements-in-haskell)

I have managed to make some progress in this part of my assignment but have attached part of the code below that I have made:

```
module Grid where

data State = On | Off deriving (Eq, Show)

next :: State -> State
next On = Off
next Off = On

type Row = [State]


updateRow :: Row -> Int -> Row
updateRow  (r:rs) x 
    | x == 0     = next r:rs
--  | otherwise     = ........????
```

As shown in the last line just above, I have managed to get updateRow to work for when x = 0, as shown below (with the 0th element inverted).

```
*Grid> updateRow [Off,Off,Off,Off] 0
[On,Off,Off,Off]
*Grid>
```

It all comes unstuck however when I try inverting other elements of this list. I can't seem to 'genralise' a formula in this function.

I also MUST follow THIS type convention:

```
updateRow :: Row -> Int -> Row
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try making updateRow recursive? It is not clear what you want to do here.

Comment: Take a look at the `slice` function

Comment: @abesto the `slice` function isn't on track.

Comment: @aleator basically making updateRow recursive may be one way to do it, but am open to all suggestions provided updateRow retains the type `updateRow :: Row -> Int -> Row`

Comment: no it isn't @Don Stewart it didn't come up in the suggestion bar. The other post I made was in relation to strings and not generic types.

Comment: @maclunian: When you down-vote, it is generally polite to comment with what you feel was wrong or misleading.  It's a bit excessive to downvote just because the answer is exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like that:

```
module Grid where

data State = On | Off deriving (Eq, Show)

next :: State -> State
next On = Off
next Off = On

type Row = [State]


updateRow :: Row -> Int -> Row
updateRow  (r:rs) x 
    | x == 0     = next r:rs
    | otherwise  = r : (updateRow rs (x-1))
updateRow [] x = []
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the function provided for you in the [previous question you asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5852722/replace-individual-list-elements-in-haskell). It works for lists of any type and I think it does what you want to do here.

Answer (score 2):

How about a general update function?

```
update i a as = map repl $ zip as [0..] where
   repl (a',i') | i == i' = a
                | otherwise = a'
```

I guess there are more performant versions, but this one is easy to understand and good enough for short lists. It replaces the `i`th element (if there is any) in `as` with `a`.

Comment: a little advanced for my league..

Comment: It looks scarier as it is: First you zip everything with its index, and then you map everything "back to normal" except for the given index (where you substitute the element).

Comment: [Cataloged here](http://www.codecatalog.net/284/)

Comment: Thanks, but wouldn't something like `update i a as = let (start, _ : end) = splitAt (i-1) as in concat [start,[a],end]` be more efficient?

Answer (score 1):

Actually the idea for the `otherwise` part of your `updateRow` function is similar to the what you have in the `replace` of your other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5852722/replace-individual-list-elements-in-haskell).

The idea is: if `x` is not zero, then you want to skip the element `r` (which is at position zero) and call `updateRow` on `rs` at a position that is `x - something` (where `something` takes into account the one position that you just skipped).

I hope this helps