# display a list of elements in ascending order

Tags: list, haskell

How would I order a list so that the list of elements appears in ascending order. I remember it was a simple haskell prelude function but now I forget (:s):

`> [1,4,5,7,9,3,1,3,5,1]`

```
[1,1,1,3,3,4,5,5,7,9]
```

Preferably without having to import modules:

Thanks for reminding me :)

Comment: `(Ord a) => [a] -> [a]` has no result for the prelude.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `sort` from `Data.List` to sort your list and then `show` it. So in a ghci session:

```
Prelude> :m +Data.List
Prelude Data.List> sort [1,4,5,7,9,3,1,3,5,1]
[1,1,1,3,3,4,5,5,7,9]
```

Comment: @maclunian Isn't that simple enough? BTW, `sort` works on all kind of elements, as long as they provide an instance of `Ord`. You can also use `sortBy` to provide your own equality test.

Comment: is there a way to do it so I don't have to import the :m +Data.List ?

Comment: @maclunian AFAIK no. There is no function in `Prelude` for sorting lists, nor is there any builtin ghci command. You can type `:?` to get a quick overview over all builtins. BTW, did you vote down?

Comment: @maclunian Why is it so bad to import a module? Those modules are standard. Its not like you are importing Parsec or something.

Comment: It was simpler. It was `List` instead of `Data.List` in Haskell98. :)

Comment: @FUZxxl I've talked to maclunian about not downvoting legit answers to his own questions [before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5987945/update-xth-element-of-list-haskell), but he seems to have a habit of it.

Comment: @maclunian Don't be that childish. Peope out there are trying to answer your questions and you just punish them with a downvote if the answer does not suits you? This is not what other people like.