# Replacing element in a list of lists in Haskell

Tags: list, search, haskell

I have a list of lists like so:

```
[["BBBBBBBB",
  "BWFFFPFGB", 
  "BWFFFPFGB",
  "BWFFMPFGB",
  "BWFFFPF_B",
  "BWFFFPF6B",
  "BBBBBBB"]]
```

I've done a little research and have found out how to access individual elements using the `!!` operator. But when it comes to searching for a certain element `'M'` I'm not sure how to go about that. My friend said I need to use something like  `(x:xs):xss`  on a list, but when I try this in the WinGHCi haskell program I get this.

```
Prelude> let list =    [["BBBBBBBB",
  "BWFFFPFGB", 
  "BWFFFPFGB",
  "BWFFMPFGB",
  "BWFFFPF_B",
  "BWFFFPF6B",
  "BBBBBBB"]]


Prelude> head(x:xs):xss
<interactive>:192:2: Not in scope: `x'
<interactive>:192:4: Not in scope: `xs'
<interactive>:192:8: Not in scope: `xss'
```

I understand that I declare the name as  `list` and not  `x:xs` but even when I declare it as  `x:xs` I still get the errors. I'm probably still a little new to haskell to really understand what to do so I may be going about this way wrong.

I've looked here [Replace individual list elements in Haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5852722/replace-individual-list-elements-in-haskell) because eventually I want to replace the `M`  with something different but I'm not completely sure how I would implement that.

Any help/guidance is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I would suggest [Learn You a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/) so you understand the basic syntax.  After you've read the first few chapters you should be able to figure out what you want.

Comment: head(x:xs):xss does not make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First let's see how to replace a `W` with `M`

```
charWM :: Char -> Char
charWM 'W' = 'M'  -- If you see W, put M.
charWM x  =  x   -- If you see anything else, put it back as is.
```

You can rewrite that function how you like by adding other letter transformations.

Now let's make that work over a list. There's a great function `map :: (a ->b) -> [a] -> [b]` that lets you apply a function on every element on a list.

```
stringWM :: String -> String
stringWM xs = map charWM xs  -- do charWM to everything in xs.
```

For example `stringWM "QWERTY WILL WIN"` = `"QMERTY MILL MIN"`

Next we can do that to a list of lists:

```
lolWM :: [String] -> [String]
lolWM xss = map stringWM xss
```

(`String` is a type synonym for `[Char]`.)
Let's test that out in ghci:

```
*Main> list'
["BBBBBBBB","BWFFFPFGB","BWFFFPFGB","BWFFMPFGB","BWFFFPF_B","BWFFFPF6B","BBBBBBB"]
*Main> lolWM list'
["BBBBBBBB","BMFFFPFGB","BMFFFPFGB","BMFFMPFGB","BMFFFPF_B","BMFFFPF6B","BBBBBBB"]
```

All good.

Your example wasn't exactly `list'`, it was `[list']` which has 1 element, so to work on that we'd need to `map lolWM`. Often we wouldn't bother writing `stringWM` or `lolWM` and go directly to lists of lists of lists, if that's what we needed:

```
lololWM = (map.map.map) charWM
```

`map.map.map` means map the map of the map. You can allow that to blow your mind a little, or you can just say list of list of list of Char, so map map map - one map per list level.

---

In the future, maybe you'll want to replace `W` with Strings instead of characters.

```
rewriteChar :: Char -> String
rewriteChar 'W' = "--^--"
rewriteChar  x  = [x] -- put x in a list to make it a string
```

This time, map isn't enough: `map rewriteChar "QWERTY WILL WIN"` gives

```
["Q","--^--","E","R","T","Y"," ","--^--","I","L","L"," ","--^--","I","N"]
```

We could use `concat` on that to flatten it into a single list, but it's more fun to do

```
rewriteString = concatMap rewriteChar
```

So now `rewriteString "QWERTY WILL WIN"` give us `"Q--^--ERTY --^--ILL --^--IN"`.

For more mindblowing things to try, there's `"QWERTY WILL WIN" >>= rewriteChar` and `"Hello Mum" >>= \x -> [x,x,x]`

Comment: thanks for this, it's pretty much what I was looking for. One question I have is how would I go about modifying this to make it so that say 1 of the strings will replace 'M' with 'W'?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, virtually all "variables" in Haskell are immutable, so there's no "changing a list", there are modified copies.

Second, you need to find an element by some criteria. To do that, you need to traverse a list. - This can be done using recursion. Filtering can be done using a function passed as an argument of your traversing function (this function must take an element and return a boolean value).

Try to put the above together and make your own function. Start with a type signature, it shows what you want to do: to take a list of Char (it's better to generalize to a generic type) and a function which possibly changes an element and return a modified list:

replaceFunc :: (Char -> Char) -> String -> String

Also, read http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/How_to_work_on_lists , there's a hint there how to apply some function to specific elements only.