# Switching 2 elements in a list by index Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, indexing

I need a function (or two) that should do something like this:

```
swap 2 [1,2,3,4] -> [1,3,2,4]
swap' 2 [1,2,3,4] -> [1,2,4,3]
```

The first integer is the index of the value I want to move to the left and to the right (it can't be 0 or the length of my list).

I know it might have been posted before, but I couldn't find anything useful.

Comment: I think this might be helpful

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5852722/replace-individual-list-elements-in-haskell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pattern matching is useful here

```
swap 1 (x:y:rest) = y:x:rest
swap n (x:y:z:rest) = x : swap (n - 1) (y:z:rest)
swap _ _ = error "Not enough elements to swap"
```

Note, this doesn't guard against non-positive `n`, you can add that feature yourself.

The logic for approaching these kinds of problems is to consider the simplest cases.  For this problem the simplest case is where you want to swap the first two elements, that's easy with pattern matching.  The next case is where you want to swap two elements that aren't the first two, but this can be reduced (via recursion) to the case where you're swapping the first two elements of a sublist.  In order to get to that case, you just decrement the index and move to the next element.  In all other cases you have an error.