# Update list with an element at a given index

Tags: haskell

Is there such function:

```
update :: a -> Int -> [a] -> Maybe [a]
```

such that it will update the list with the element at given index, or return `Nothing` if the index is out of boundary?

For example:

```
> update 9 1 [3,4,5]
Just [3,9,5]

> update 4 2 [3,4,5]
Just [3,4,4]

> update 6 5 [3,4,5]
Nothing
```

Comment: Uhhh, why would you want to deliberately throw an error when this can be handled purely eg. `update :: a -> Int -> [a] -> Maybe [a]` or `... -> ([a],Bool)`? Well, I mean, you can always throw something manually according to your needs, but it doesn't "belong" in the `update` function.

Comment: Good suggestion

Comment: If the index is out of bounds, why not just return the original list? I don't think that's any more ambiguous than if you tried to replace an element which the value that was already there. (This is in the same spirit as `take` returning the longest list it can if the request size is greater than the length of the argument.)

Comment: According to [hoogle](https://hoogle.haskell.org) there is no such a function but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5852820) answer is what you need.

Comment: @chepner I think a Maybe is more principled. You can always go from a Maybe version to a self-returning version by just inspecting the Maybe, but if the only version you have always returns `[a]` it's not cheap to tell whether the replacement was successful or not.

Comment: @amalloy Not quite; how do I get `[1,2,3]` back from `update 1 4 [1,2,3]` if it returns `Nothing`? Attempting to update a non-existent location just feels more like a no-op than an error to me. The location didn't exist before you call `update`; and it won't exist after.

Comment: @amalloy @chepner the lens library fails silently, `[1,2,3] & ix 5 .~ 8 = [1,2,3]`. The `at` Lens (which unlike `ix` deals in `Maybe`s in order to insert/remove elements rather than just change them) has no instance on lists, which I guess makes sense (eg. if you try the above example, what do you put in the newly-created cells 3,4 as a default value?). Just providing a comparison point in the design space.

Comment: @chepner Of course, you can't recover it from just the Nothing, but you can keep around the original list: `let xs = [1..5] in fromMaybe xs $ update 9 1 xs`

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it like this. Of particular note, it doesn't use any partial functions or incomplete pattern matches, even in places where hitting them would "never" happen. It also correctly handles the case of a negative index, immediately returning `Nothing` rather than looping forever.

```
update :: a -> Int -> [a] -> Maybe [a]
update y = go
  where
    go _ [] = Nothing -- whoops, called update with too large an index
    go i (x:xs) = case i `compare` 0 of
      LT -> Nothing -- whoops, called update with a negative index
      EQ -> Just (y:xs)
      GT -> (x:) <$> update y (pred i) xs
```

Comment: maybe add another clause at the top, to handle the negative index just once?

Answer (score 0):

It can be written quite brutally:

```
update val idx l =
  if idx >= length l || idx < 0
  then Nothing
  else updateUnsafe val idx l

updateUnsafe _ _ [] = error "Empty List"
updateUnsafe val idx (h:t) =
  if idx == 0 then val:t
  else h:(updateUnsafe val (idx - 1) t)
```

Or tail recursive:

```
updateUnsafe val idx = reverse . go [] val idx where
  go acc _ _ [] = acc
  go acc v i (h:t) = go ((if i == 0 then v else h) : t) v (i - 1) t
```

However, both of them will loop infinitely when we get never ending list which can be fixed in the first case. We may rewrite `updateUnsafe` not to throw an error, but to let it operate on `Maybe` type instead:

```
update _ idx _ | idx < 0 = Nothing
update _ _ [] = Nothing
update val idx (h:t) =
  if idx == 0 then Just $ val:t
  else (h:) <$> (updateUnsafe val (idx - 1) t)
```

---

I don't see any function that would solve it in the standard [Data.List](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-List.html) library

Comment: The first version is quite dangerous, since it will loop infinitely on an infinite list.

Comment: I think `Data.List.splitAt` would help a lot here. Something like `case splitAt idx xs of (_, []) -> error ".." ; (before, _:after) -> before ++ val : after `